# Htaccess multiple redirect rules should be working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This should be working according to htaccess tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

I'm trying to get url's in the format subdomain.domain.com to resolve to domain.com/index.php?sub=subdomain

However I've also want any links in the form subdomain.domain.com/pagename to redirect to domain.com/index.php?tpl=page&sub=subdomain&url=pagename

At the moment the first rule works if i remove the second rule but if I include both only the second rule works.

Here's the full htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#EDIT: this was messing it all up by appending index.html so the subdomain only 
# wasn't triggering at all due to appended pagename
DirectoryIndex disabled


#Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Rewrite if subdomain only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?sub=%1 [P,NC,QSA,L]

#Rewrite if internal page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?([^/]*)$ http://example.com/index.php?tpl=page&sub=%1&url=$2 [P,NC,QSA,L]
```

If you answer this I will make you Secretary of State once Flat Earth goes mainstream. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On

#Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

#Rewrite if subdomain only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%2/index.php?sub=%1 [P,QSA,NC,L]

#Rewrite if internal page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?([^/]+)/?$ http://%2/index.php?tpl=page&sub=%1&url=$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change url=$1 for the pagenames to work in your one, the "subdomain only" rule works fine using htaccess tester but I found that for some reason the server or browser is always appending index.html as the pagename which makes it always think there's a pagename for some reason.. I don't know how to prevent this seems automatic. The code I posted seems to be working as well.

Comment: I found adding DirectoryIndex disabled
solves the issue of index.html being appended.

Comment: The DirectoryIndex disabled blocks the homepage so the www redirect code isn't working now... I'm trying to figure out how to keep directoryindex disabled but not have index.html appended to every url. I tried options -indexes but that doesn't work at all on the server. I may need to send the user explicitly to domain.com/index.php in the www redirect. This would change the url as it's a 301 so I need to do this seperately perhaps.